# Promise.catch() not catching errors from promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, catch-block

I'm trying to check a number of conditions, and if one of them is true I want to proceed to a certain callback function. Otherwise, I want to proceed to a different callback function. Some pseudocode might look like:

```
if (condition_1 OR condition_2 OR condition_3) {
    on_satisfied()
} else {
    on_unsatisfied()
}
```

However, checking each of these conditions takes a while (for example, it may require a database query), so I want to check them asynchronously. I also know that if any one of them returns TRUE, I have already satisfied my condition and thus want to stop execution and forget about the remaining conditions. In hopes of doing that, I wanted to use the "dirty trick" described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383852/how-to-terminate-parent-function-execution-in-javascript) in the first response: throwing an error that will be handled within a parent function (which is inside a promise here)

```js
// the function we call if at least one condition is satisfied
function on_satisfied() {
    console.log("At least one condition satisfied")
}

// the function we call if no conditions are satisfied
function on_unsatisfied() {
    console.log("No conditions satisfied")
}

// a sample condition-checking function
async function check_lessthan_5(to_check, callback_if_not) {
    // using a timeout to simulate "slow" checking of conditions;
    // the slow checking could be a result of e.g. database queries
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    if (to_check < 5) {
        // throw this error in hopes of terminating parent function,
        // because it is sufficient for one condition to be met 
        // in order for the whole OR-joined expression to be true (we want to stop execution of the parent function)
        throw Error("value < 5")
    }
    return false
}

const all_cond_checker = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // store all the resulting promises, 
    // so when they all resolve we know that no conditions were satisfied
    var conditions_list = []
    // check all the conditions. In this case, we want to see if any of these numbers is >= 5
    for (var i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // push a resulting promise into the list, we can check later that it resolves
        // if the condition is met, terminate this function by propagating error up
        conditions_list.push(check_lessthan_5(i)).catch((error) => {resolve()})
    }
    // once all the promises return, us getting here implies no errors were thrown 
    // which implies no conditions satisfied
    Promise.all(conditions_list).then(reject)
});
```

The problem is that it seems like the `.catch()` inside the promise does not catch the error! Running the code, I get the following:

```
$ node async_test.js
No conditions satisfied
/home/daniel/Signoff-again/node-experiments/async_test.js:20
            throw Error("value >= 5")
            ^

Error: value < 5
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/daniel/Signoff-again/node-experiments/async_test.js:20:19)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

My interpretation of these results is that, for some reason, the .catch() is totally skipped, the error is unhandled, the `for`-loop is broken, then the Promise.all() is executed (because all 5 of the Promises in `conditions_list` have been resolved) and so the `on_unsatisfied` function is called. Instead, what I would want/expect is for the `on_satisfied` function to be called as soon as the first `check_lessthan_5` returns.

So the question: why is it happening that the `catch()` seems not to work here? Also, is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

I expect that as soon as the first condition is satisfied, the returned error is caught by the `.catch()` in `all_cond_checker` and then `on_satisfied` is called. I do not expect the error to propagate all the way "out" and be reported in the console.

The expected console output is:

```
$ node async_test.js
At least one condition satisfied
```

Comment: You're calling `.catch` on the return of `push`, not on the promise. That would cause an error by itself if the previous error wasn't raised.

Comment: You know that the OR operator is || in js right? not just "OR"

Comment: You have `….push(…).catch(…)` instead of `….push(check_lessthan_5(i).catch(…))`

Comment: "*we want to stop execution of the parent function*" - that does not actually stop the evaluation of the other conditions, which are still waiting for their timeouts separately.

Comment: `push(...).catch(...)` would have also been an error on its own so if you just logged the error you were getting, you would have likely seen that the `.catch()` wasn't working.  ALWAYS log whatever error you get.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that actually makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @Hermanboxcar yes, I just intended to write pseudocode that gave the idea. I wanted to avoid hinting at an implementation, because otherwise someone may say, "why don't you just do that?"

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the suggestion! It seems I should have tried not throwing my own error, because that was the only one logged. I had no idea a different error would otherwise be thrown; but thanks for pointing that out, it will help me a lot to debug!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have the catch in the wrong place

```js
async function check_lessthan_5(to_check) {
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));
  if (to_check < 5) {
    throw Error('value < 5');
  }
  return false;
}

const all_cond_checker = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var conditions_list = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    conditions_list.push(check_lessthan_5(i));
  }
  Promise.all(conditions_list)
    .then((r) => resolve(r))
    .catch((err) => reject(err));
});

all_cond_checker
  .then((r) => console.log(r))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Thank you Chris, I'll try your suggestion this evening and then accept it as the answer. It also does seem like this would stop the evaluation of the remaining conditions, which is exactly what I want!

Comment: @DanielShteinbok Nope. Nothing is stopping or cancelling the active `setTimeout` timers.

Comment: @Bergi makes sense, thank you! I just checked with a new function `check_morethan` and logged all the checks, indeed the remainder of the checks are done anyway. But the important thing is that this *does* return before the unnecessary checks are performed, leading to the minimal execution time that I wanted. Thanks again to Chris and everyone that answered.

Comment: @DanielShteinbok Yes, but that's just the default behaviour of `Promise.all`, to reject as soon as any input promise rejects.